# Nth term of geometric series where each term is rounded to two decimal places

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I know that the nth term of a geometric series is

$$f(n, a_1) = a_n = a_1 r^{n-1}$$

In my case however, since I am dealing with money, I am rounding each term to two decimal places. I calculate the nth term using the previous term like so

$$
g(n, a_{n-1}) = a_n = round(a_{n-1}r)
$$
where
$$
a_1 = 1000; 
r = 1.000833333
$$

As you can see below, using $f$ will produce a discrepancy. For example, see below how rounding $f(2)$ will produce 1001.67 rather than 1001.66

```
n  f()          g()      
1  1000.833333  1000.83  
2  1001.667361  1001.66
```

What is the formula to calculate the nth term of this geometric series where each term is rounded to two decimal places?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Just updated, is that clear?

Comment: Rounding is a non-trivial nonlinearity. I don't believe you will find a formula to do this without recursion. Are you asking for an explicit formula?

Comment: Yes I am asking for an explicit formula. Oh well, at least it would be good to hear confirmation that a formula is not possible. Thanks!